# My sidebar items, right border looks different in different browsers

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

The right border of the sidebar item looks different in different browsers. In my case Mozilla and Chrome. So how can I solve this problem?

Here is the images from Mozilla and Chrome below:

[image: From Mozilla View image]

[image: From Chrome View image]

```
"use client";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { LucideIcon } from "lucide-react"
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

interface SidebarItemProps {
    icon: LucideIcon;
    label: string;
    href: string;
}

export const SidebarItem = ({ icon: Icon, label, href }: SidebarItemProps) => {
    const pathname = usePathname()
    const router = useRouter()


    const isActive =
        (pathname === "/" && href === "/") ||
        pathname === href ||
        pathname?.startsWith(`${href}/`)

    const onClick = () => {
        router.push(href)
    }

    return (
        <button
            onClick={onClick}
            type="button"
            className={cn(
                "flex items-center gap-x-2 text-slate-500 text-sm font-[500] pl-6 transition-all hover:text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-300/20", isActive && "text-sky-700 bg-sky-200/20 hover:bg-sky-200/20 hover:text-sky-700"
            )}
        >
            <div className="flex items-center gap-x-2 py-4">
                <Icon
                    size={22}
                    className={cn(
                        "text-slate-500",
                        isActive && "text-sky-700"
                    )}
                />
                {label}
            </div>
            {/* Right Active Border */}
            <div
                className={cn(
                    "ml-auto opacity-0 border-2 border-sky-700 h-full transition-all",
                    isActive && "opacity-100"
                )}
            />
        </button>
    )
}
```

I want to see the same result in Mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: Please provide some more informations, like code, or atleast image from mozilla for compare what is diffrence

Comment: Image and code added

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should remove "items-center" from button class list

It give button css align-items: center; which override default display: flex; align-items

By default align-items have value stretch which mean items of fled will be expanded to similar height

Comment: I've removed the "items-center" but it didn't work. It's only happening on Mozilla but in Chrome its fine

Comment: @FarhadHossain instead of border try to use background-color and set and width instead of border width